# VSCode Remap keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been trying for awhile now to remap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keys to switch editor tabs linearly. (Like they would in Chrome)

I have learned that by default, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd> keys have the functionality I desire. However, whether it be through the graphical Keyboard Shortcut page or the `keybindings.json` file, I cannot get the keys to do what I want them to.

Relevant parts of `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+pagedown",
  "command": "-selectNextPageSuggestion"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+pageup",
  "command": "-selectPrevPageSuggestion"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+tab",
  "command": "-workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+tab",
  "command": "-workbench.action.openPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+tab",
  "command": "selectNextPageSuggestion"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+tab",
  "command": "selectPrevPageSuggestion"
}
```

Theoretically, I believe that this should work, but it only disables the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keys entirely, and doesn't give them the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd> behavior that I am after.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems overly complicated.  I just put the following into my keybindings.json file and it is working perfectly:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+tab",         "command": "workbench.action.nextEditor" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+tab",   "command": "workbench.action.previousEditor" },
```

It doesn't disable  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd> but does add the new functionality you desire.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't come across those commands earlier.

Comment: I just searched for ctrl+pagedown and ctrl+pageup in the default keybindings.  Open the Keyboard shortcuts from the gear icon and click on the easy to miss keybindings.json link at the top which should open a split panel with the default keybindings on top and your overrides underneath.  Then I searched for those key sequences and copied what you wanted into my override file below and gave them the keystrokes you wanted.

Comment: Ah, Yes. My search function was throwing me off. I see it now.