# How to toggle between opened tabs in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was looking at default keybindings but didn't find it. 
Is it even possible by default to toggle between opened tabs in VS Code? 
If no, maybe you know extension for doing so?

Thanks!

Comment: I mean to toggle between tabs like using Alt+Tab in Windows to toggle between different opened applications.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416552/vscode-remap-keyboard-shortcut/46417103#46417103  ctrl-pageup and ctrl-pagedown

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSCode Remap keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416552/vscode-remap-keyboard-shortcut)

Answer (score 10):

On a Mac, ctrl-tab does exactly what you're asking for. I'm not sure what the equivalent is for Windows or Linux.

Comment: same for Ubuntu

Comment: Same in vs studio in windows. Forgot about vs code. But im pretty sure its the same there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's an OS standard, works across apps. Working in Chrome, Works in Finder, ...

Comment: Except that this doesn't switch tabs like it does in other applications, it just navigates tab history, which can be somewhat unintuitive.

Answer (score 6):

In windows `CTRL+PgUp` to previous tab and `CTRL+PgDown` to next tab.

Answer (score 2):

> When using Visual Studio Code on Linux/Windows, you can use CTRL + PAGE_UP to switch to the previous tab, and CTRL + PAGE_DN to switch to the next tab. You also have the ability to switch to tabs based on their (non-zero relative) index. You can do so, by pressing and holding ALT , followed by a number (1 through 9).

For more details: [check here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_keyboard-shortcuts)